# check and list the existing value first in php

Tags: php

I have users table in which it has

```
name        email
abc       xxx@yyy.com
def       xyz@yyy.com
ghi      
jkl       xyx@yyy.com
```

Now i want to check the email exist or not. if exist i want to list that first, then the output will be

```
name        email
abc       xxx@yyy.com
def       xyz@yyy.com          
jkl       xyx@yyy.com
ghi
```

Comment: well then simply go `...your query ORDER BY ( email = "value" ), email` having the one matching your given mail address listed first (true) and otherwhise sorted via adresses

Comment: Have you tried `ORDER BY email = 'xxx@yyy.com' DESC`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use

```
<your query> ORDER BY email DESC
```

with this the users having email will come first and users with no emails will be listed at end.